# Как программно сменить иконку приложения?

Tags: java, android

Мне надо программно реализовать смену иконки приложения. И желательно чтобы после перезагрузки устройства она осталась. Искал ответ в google, нашёл только рекламу APK Editor и прочей ерунды. Как же лучше всего сделать смену иконки?

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал такие варианты:

1)

```
MainContentObj.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.png")));    ////Путь определите свой
```

2)

```
try {
    Image icon = ImageIO.read(MainContent.class.getResourceAsStream("images/icon.png"));
    MainContentObj.setIconImage(icon);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: `public void getGreenIcon (View v) { //ваш код }` можно прямо так?

Comment: не понял вопроса? ну проверьте, и узнаете можно или нет.